# How to get output of the cost function in an optimizer [scipy.minimise('method=’SLSQP’)]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While running scipy minimise optimizer, I am able to get the solution of the optimization by using the "x" attribute of the optimized results. But I would like to get the value of the cost function (the function that is being minimized by varying the input variable,x) as well.

```
# Objective Function
def op_objective(x):
   mini = <some function of x>
   return mini

# Equality Constraint
def constraint1(x):
    return 1-sum(x)

# Initializing the constraint
con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons = ([con1])

# Calling the optimizer
opt = minimize(op_objective,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)

# Optimized solution
sol = opt.x
```

Now the question is how to get the value of "mini" for which the value of "x" is captured.

Running the  for the final value of "x" to determine the value of "mini" is an option, but looking for a more direct approach since this one is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) takes a callback function that is called on every iteration and can be used to print the state.

Simple example:

```
f = lambda x: x**2
def callback(params): 
    print(f(params))
minimize(f, x0=np.array([10]), callback=callback)
```